# ROS Answers SE migration: pcl bag_to_pcd

Tags: ros, pcl, pcd, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to convert a bagfile into pcd files using bag_to_pcd. But
everything I get is

[ERROR] [1297703460.328842013]: You requested a transform at time
1292497206.348,
but the tf buffer only contains a single transform at time 1292497207.122.
When trying to transform between /head_tof_link and /base_link.

What's wrong? Replaying the bag file using rosbag play seems to work
correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9047/pcl-bag_to_pcd/) by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default I believe that bag_to_pcd uses /base_link as the output TF transform. This should be exposed properly through
a parameter. You can either modify it yourself (line 133) and submit a patch, or ticket me and I'll make sure it gets fixed.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3